# Firebase ValueEventListener not executing sequentially

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read Art object from Realtime Firebase using artId following the sequence 2,1,2. Before the execution, I used Log.d to print out the artId and it shows the intended sequence (2,1,2), however inside the onDataChange(), it shows 2,2,1. Why is that? Anyway to solve it?

Code:

```
for(cartItem in cartItemList) {
    Log.d(TAG, "cartItem artId: " + cartItem.artId) //Prints 2,1,2

    val artQuery = artRef.child(cartItem.artId.toString()) //supposed to be 2,1,2
    artQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val art = snapshot.getValue(Art::class.java)!!
            Log.d(TAG, "artId: "+art.artId) //result is 2,2,1 instead, why?
        }

    })
}
```

Reatime Database Structure:

```
"Art" : [ null, {
    "artId" : "1",
    "artImg" : "-",
    "artName" : "-",
    "artistId" : "-",
    "description" : "-",
    "price" : 0,
    "stockQty" : 0
  }, {
    "artId" : "2",
    "artImg" : "-",
    "artName" : "-",
    "artistId" : "-",
    "description" : "-",
    "price" : 0,
    "stockQty" : 0
  }
```

Comment: That sounds unexpected: the SDK sends the calls to the server in the order in which you make them, and the server handles in that same order. Can you show the database structure that you're loading (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, i've included the structure in the question. I've tried to use 'addValueEventListener', at first, it is not working. But i've found a way which is re-entering the fragment, meaning when first entering of the fragment, order is incorrect, i navigate away, then navigate back again, this time, the order is correct. Weird.

Comment: If you run the same code several times, are you always getting the same exact result?

Comment: @AlexMamo Erm, i've restarted the application quite a lot of times and the results are still the same. If there are no people encountering this problem, I think it is my own code implementation that causes this but not sure where, I'll check on it.